# T-SQL Return XML values as dataset with rows

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm struggling with querying a SQL table and returning each row and also splitting out all the "Expressions" xml records into separate rows. I'm tried a few approaches.

This is some test data. I'm hoping to get 2 rows back both id an ID column of 1 and then some columns showing all the attributes of each expression.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #MyData (ID INT, MyXML xml)
INSERT INTO #MyData SELECT
1 AS ID
,'<ArrayOfExpressions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Expressions>
    <ExpressionID>1</ExpressionID>
    <FieldName>AlternateDescription</FieldName>
    <Operator>is not filled out</Operator>
    <Condition>777</Condition>
    <AndOr>OR</AndOr>
  </Expressions>
  <Expressions>
    <ExpressionID>2</ExpressionID>
    <FieldName>InputMask</FieldName>
    <Operator>does not contain</Operator>
    <Condition>hello</Condition>
    <AndOr>AND</AndOr>
  </Expressions>
</ArrayOfExpressions>' AS MyXML
```

And based on some examples this is as far as I got but I'm a bit lost now....

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(select 
       ID
       ,MyXMLRows.ExpressionID.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as ExpressionID
from 
       #MyData CROSS APPLY
       MyXML.nodes('/ArrayOfExpressions/Expressions') AS Roles(MyXMLRows)
)  as MyResults
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    ExpressionId = XC.value('(ExpressionID)[1]', 'int'),
    FieldName = XC.value('(FieldName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Operator = XC.value('(Operator)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Condition = XC.value('(Condition)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    AndOr = XC.value('(AndOr)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
FROM
    #MyData
CROSS APPLY
    MyXML.nodes('/ArrayOfExpressions/Expressions') AS XT(XC)
```

That should return something like this a a result set:

| ID | ExpressionId | FieldName | Operator | Condition | AndOr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | AlternateDescription | is not filled out | 777 | OR |
| 1 | 2 | InputMask | does not contain | hello | AND |